# Prevent Ducking with iOSBluetoothHandsFree

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, iobluetooth

I am writing an application for Mac OSX in Xcode/Objective-C that uses the `IOBluetoothHandsFree` class in the `IOBluetooth` module. The application allows a user to use their computer as a speakerphone for their phone over bluetooth. I'm running into an issue where the volume of all other applications on the computer get much lower when a call is initialized and the computer is used as the speakerphone (called "audio ducking"). How can I go about disabling this functionality in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with the Apple Bluetooth team, it turns out that this feature is not supported in the latest version of the IOBluetoothHandsFree class.